# How to integrate a spring boot application using spring cloud stream to IBM event streams on bluemix cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

### My requirement is to connect a Spring cloud stream application to IBM event streams.

Pom file contains the dependency - spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka

Controller code

```
private final GreetingsService greetingsService;
public GreetingsController(GreetingsService greetingsService) {
      super();
      this.greetingsService = greetingsService;
  }
  @RequestMapping(value="/sendgreetings",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void sendGreetings(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
      System.out.println("message " + message);
      Greetings greetings = new Greetings(System.currentTimeMillis(), message);
      greetingsService.sendGreeting(greetings);
  }
```

Greetings Listener class

```
 @Component
public class GreetingsListener 
{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingsListener.class);

@StreamListener(GreetingsStream.INPUT)
public void handleGreetings(@Payload Greetings greetings) {
    LOG.info("Received Greetings {}", greetings);
}

 }
```

Greetings Stream interface

```
 public interface GreetingsStream {

 String INPUT = "greetings-in";
 String OUTPUT = "greetings-out";

 @Input(INPUT)
SubscribableChannel inBoundGreetings();

@Output(OUTPUT)
MessageChannel outBoundGreetings();

}
```

Greetings Service

```
 @Service
 public class GreetingsService {

private final GreetingsStream greetingsStream;

public GreetingsService(GreetingsStream greetingsStream) {
    super();
    this.greetingsStream = greetingsStream;
}


public void sendGreeting(final Greetings greetings) {

    MessageChannel messageChannel = greetingsStream.outBoundGreetings();
    messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.
            withPayload(greetings)
            //.setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)     
            .build());
  }
}
```

Greetings Class

```
 @Getter @Setter @ToString @Builder
 public class Greetings {

 private long timestamp;
 private String message;

 public Greetings() {

 }

public Greetings(long timestamp, String message) {
    super();
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
}


 }
```

Binding

```
 @EnableBinding(GreetingsStream.class)
 public class EventstreamConfig {}
```

Main Class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class EventstreamApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EventstreamApplication.class, args);
 }
 }
```

I am able to connect, send and receive messages to local Kafka instance with the below configurations specified in the properties file

```
 server:
   port : 8082
 spring:
   cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
           brokers: localhost:9092
     bindings:
         greetings-in:
           destination: greetings
           contentType: application/json
         greetings-out:
           destination: greetings
           contentType: application/json
```

However i am not able to connect to the IBM event streams on blue mix cloud.
Below is my configurations to connect to Event Streams on cloud

```
    spring:
       cloud:
        stream:
          kafka:
            binder:
               brokers: kafk*****et:9093
               consumerProperties: 
                 group-id: foo
                 auto-offset-reset: earliest
          key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
         value-deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer       
              producerProperties:
                 client-id: eventstream
         key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
         value-deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer 
              configuration: 
                 security:
                   protocol: SASL_SSL
                 sasl:
                   mechanism: PLAIN  
              jaas:
                 enabled: true
                 loginModule:org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule  
                 options: 
                   username: ***
                   password: ***
       bindings:
          greetings-in:
          destination: greetings
          contentType: application/json
          greetings-out:
          destination: greetings
          contentType: application/json
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the configurations. I did not find any example for my requirement.

```
 This is the error i am getting.
    2019-12-28 15:57:46.832  WARN 5780 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2181)]   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]

2019-12-28 15:57:46.948  INFO 5780 --- [127.0.0.1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-28 15:57:48.973  WARN 5780 --- [127.0.0.1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]

2019-12-28 15:57:50.078  INFO 5780 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-28 15:57:52.100  WARN 5780 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]

2019-12-28 15:57:52.201  INFO 5780 --- [127.0.0.1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-28 15:57:54.210  WARN 5780 --- [127.0.0.1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) ~[zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8--1]

2019-12-28 15:57:55.328  INFO 5780 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-28 15:57:57.458  INFO 5780 --- [           main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Session: 0x0 closed
2019-12-28 15:57:57.462  WARN 5780 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
2019-12-28 15:57:57.467  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-12-28 15:57:57.467  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2019-12-28 15:57:57.468  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: greetings-out
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: greetings-in
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler@681c0ae6
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-12-28 15:57:57.469  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2019-12-28 15:57:57.473  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-12-28 15:57:57.473  INFO 5780 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@44bc2449: startup date [Sat Dec 28 15:57:44 IST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67ab1c47
2019-12-28 15:57:57.480  INFO 5780 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-28 15:57:57.458  INFO 5780 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : EventThread shut down for session: 0x0
2019-12-28 15:57:57.500  INFO 5780 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-28 15:57:57.516 ERROR 5780 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at com.example.eventstream.EventstreamApplication.main(EventstreamApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:137) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:138) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130) ~[zkclient-0.9.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicsIfAutoCreateEnabledAndAdminUtilsPresent(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

> `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

This simply means the host/port is wrong for zookeeper.

> at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
>
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]

You are using a very old version of SCSt (1.3.x); the binder has not talked directly to Zookeeper since 2.0.

Comment: The error is pointing to Zookeeper, not Kafka / port 9093, though

Comment: Hmm - yes; (s)he is using a very old version. The binder hasn't connected directly to zookeeper since version 2.0.